# With what to start when creating a cross-platform app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, react-native

So I have a well-planned idea for an app, and I want to implement it in the next year.

I did my research and decided to learn JS ,CSS and HTML using NATIVE REACT and FIREBASE.

My question is, where do I start?
Should I first learn HTML?JS?CSS? or maybe all together is the same time? maybe focusing on something else which will provide strong foundations? what will speed up the learning curve?

( P.s - I'm a second year student in software Engineering, so learning new skills & technologies is quite familiar. )

Answer (score 1):

HTML, CSS and JavaScript in this order is a good choice.
They will all be useful in future, and rely on each other.